# How to add field "states" in Signup page Odoo?

Tags: authentication, select, state, odoo, checkout

I need to add the field "states" in my page Sinup page of Odoo 8.

The field appears correctly in the page, but i don't have the list of states...

Why?

This is my controller:

```
import logging
import werkzeug
import openerp
from openerp.addons.auth_signup.res_users import SignupError
from openerp.addons.web.controllers.main import ensure_db
from openerp import http
from openerp.http import request
from openerp.addons.website_sale.controllers.main import website_sale
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def login_redirect_a():
url = '/sale_login?'
# built the redirect url, keeping all the query parameters of the url
redirect_url = '%s?%s' % (
    request.httprequest.base_url, werkzeug.urls.url_encode(request.params))
return """<html><head><script>
window.location = '%sredirect=' + encodeURIComponent("%s" + location.hash);
</script></head></html>
""" % (url, redirect_url)

@http.route(['/sale_login'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)

def do_signup(self, qcontext):
    """ Shared helper that creates a res.partner out of a token """
    values = dict((key, qcontext.get(key))
                  for key in ('login', 'name', 'password', 'state_id', 'country_id'))
    assert any([k for k in values.values()]
               ), "The form was not properly filled in."
    assert values.get('password') == qcontext.get(
        'confirm_password'), "Passwords do not match; please retype them."
    values['lang'] = request.lang
    self._signup_with_values(qcontext.get('token'), values)
    request.cr.commit()

def get_auth_signup_qcontext(self):
    """ Shared helper returning the rendering
    context for signup and reset password """
    qcontext = request.params.copy()
    qcontext['states'] = request.env["res.country.state"].sudo().search([])
qcontext['countries'] = request.env["res.country"].sudo().search([])
    return qcontext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is why do you expect to get the list of states in your `new` field to be loaded, how?
For get it loaded you would need to do a python extension to the `AuthSignupHome` controller, specifically to override the method `get_auth_signup_qcontext` to add the list of states like:

```
from openerp.http import request
from openerp.addons.auth_signup.controllers.main import AuthSignupHome

class AuthSignupHomeExt(AuthSignupHome):

    def get_auth_signup_qcontext(self):
        qcontext = super(AuthSignupHomeExt, self).get_auth_signup_qcontext()
        qcontext['states'] = request.env["res.country.state"].sudo().search([])
        return qcontext
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your quick response. I have an error with your code :               File "/mnt/extra-addons/account_sign_up_details/controllers/main.py", line 18, in get_auth_signup_qcontext
    qcontext = super(AuthSignupHomeExt, self).create()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'create'

Comment: Sorry, copy paste error. It's updated with the super call to `get_auth_signup_qcontext`

Comment: The error is : 'super' object has no attribute 'create' , i have Internal Sever Error. Please help...

Comment: Can i use this code to another page different to Sign up page?

Comment: Depending on the page and their code, methods and controller classes the logic of adding values to the final qweb context it's the same. You already know how to use it in the template. Could you give an upvote too?

Comment: I can't, when a want to do it, i have a message that "i have less than 15 reputation"...Please Axel, in my another page, i don't have the list of my states... the problem is still here...Can i give you my module in e-mail to see this?...

Comment: You could share it on github or gitlab to be able to look at it. You could contact me by email if you wanna hire consultancy or development service.

Comment: Hello Axel, i changed my question by adding my controller. The question is : I have a page "sale_login" where the user can register and connect before checkout. But here i want to add the fields "states" and "country" in registration of this page. The list of my states and country doesn't appear...